# Using window.print() on mobile screen (iphone) only prints the webpage to the screen size in preview

Tags: css, angular, printing

I am using window.print() to print out labels for webpage. It works on desktop screens to print out the labels in a grid format. However, on iPhone the screen cuts off the page and only shows the content to the screen size of the device.

I have set print specific css to try to force the page to show the desktop view on print only. The styles apply but the print preview is still cut to be only the size of the iphone screen.

```
@media print {
  body {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .non-printable {
    display: none;
  }

  @page {
    size: 8in 11in;
    margin: 1in;
  }

  #section-to-print {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);

    .label:nth-of-type(10) {
      break-after: always;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What settings have you got, paper size, scaling and so on?